# nativescript livereload on device

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-cli

i am using https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular2-seed-advanced which creates a running nativescript app.

now, i am a starter with nativescript and wanted to ask, how i can achieve a good development flow.

i am coming from ionic where i was able to see the console output on my development machine and was able to test my app live on a cable connected device. live reloading was running also.

so my questions:

1. can i run my app on a device without publishing it to the store
2. will i be able to see the console.log output somehow on my local dev machine with adb or a nativescript cli command?
3. is live reloading possible for developing nativescript apps?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

1. yes
2. yes
3. yes

   tns livesync android --watch

Answer (score 3):

1. You can install the app to your own Android / iOS real devices and/or the iOS simulator and Android emulators, all without sending it to any of the stores.
2. You can see the log fine, typically when you do a **tns run [ios|android]** the log is pipped back to your console.  You can also run the standard **adb logcat** (android) or **idevicesyslog** (for iOS if installed)
3. Live reloading is possible, and works fairly well.  You can use the **tns run [android|ios]** which is built into the tns command line.

Comment: How would you do live sync with MS Code and debugging? I'm trying to get this working so that it doesn't take 3-5 minutes to build every time I make a change with no luck. Brutally slow for development without it.

Comment: Sorry; I don't use MS VCode; I use phpStorm and my own LiveEdit plugin on Android for most my development.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all three questions is yes (as another answer point out). To add to answer of question 3,
As of nativescript version 2.5.0, `tns run` and `tns livesync` does the same thing, `tns run` has the ability to apply changes and sync it to a running app on device/emulator. The message on console clearly says `tns livesync` is being deprecated, so you should always look to use `tns run`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the latest options(As of 2018-Jan) to run the app in live sync mode with a device when you are using NathanWalker -angular-seed-advanced.

```
iOS (device):   npm run start.ios.device --debug
Android (device):  npm run start.android.device --debug
```

`--debug` option will pull in more logs from the device(not just for your app, but also other activities)

Check the latest [doc here](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced#dev-workflow) for up-to date commands,

You can also use adb as explained [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/),

Comment: Those who down vote, but not bothering to add a comment explaining why, please grow up! Seriously. Don't undermine someones effort to help by answering. Down votes are perfectly fine, when explained with a comment, so the answer can either be corrected or will at least let readers know why to refrain from it.

Comment: And on this specific answer, do see the documentation from the link provided. These are the exact commands to be used(when using the seed project mentioned in the question) as of mentioned date, which is not reflecting in the old answer and so I added this answer with date.